# django performance optimization

Tags: python, mysql, django, encryption

I have the following problem:

My employers wanted some fields in the database to have encrypted values. So I used one of django apps (django-encrypted-fields) to have them encrypted. But then came the issue that if you wanted to filter database records using those fields it couldn't be done. The only solution was to execute the query normal using a for on the queryset, so to obtain db record's value and make the filtering. But this add a very heavy load when you have to filter using for 1000 or more records. The time to fullfill the request gets bigger when you have more than 10 simultaneous requests on the same thing. Is there a way to optimize this kind of search?

some example code

```
#getting search terms cause not all of them are stored on a model (blank=True, null=True)
search_terms = {}
for field in post_data.keys():
print "Checking field ", field
if post_data[field] is not None and post_data[field] != "":
    print "Adding to search terms"
    search_terms.update({field:post_data[field]})

customers = Customer.objects.filter(practice=practice_data)
search_result = []
for customer in customers:
    satisfies = True
    #every post data has the same name like my customer fields to make search easy
    for field in search_terms.keys():                         
        if getattr(customer, field):
            #checking to see if if the value posted is of date or user type(obj)                 
            if isinstance(search_terms[field], date) or isinstance(search_terms[field], get_user_model()):
                 #if it don't match, dont bother cheking the rest 
                 if getattr(customer, field) != search_terms[field]:
                     satisfies = False
                     break

            #if its string then just check if it mathces the start of the customer field
            elif not getattr(customer,field).lower().startswith(search_terms[field].lower()):
                satisfies = False
                break

         #if customer property was blank then it won't match
         else:                                
             satisfies = False

         #if it matches added to the results
         if satisfies:
             search_result.append(customer)
```

I user getattr to check if specific field is not blank or null and isinstance to check if post data is of a specific type (cause lower() won't work with dates and objects). Its very poor code but don't know how to optimize this kind of filtering when you have most of your fields encrypted

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get around fetching and decrypting the data if you're looking for substring matches. If you're testing for equality, though, you can first encrypt the desired search term and then do a `filter()` on that.

Comment: Is it better if I do list(queryset) and then start my "filtering"?